# Should this question have been migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

Should [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6766/show-and-hide-elements-in-jquery#8470635) have been migrated from StackOverflow to CodeReview?  OP was asking a fairly specific question about how to do something with jQuery; he wasn't simply asking for feedback on his code.

Comment: Trigger: "The following solution looks like it needs refactoring"

Comment: Looks like it had a good outcome. Two answers with upvotes, one accepted answer. What's the problem?

Comment: @Robert - not so much a problem, just wondering if migrating this was really appropriate.

Comment: If it was a productive move, it was appropriate.  Granted, one can't always judge whether or not a question will be received well on another site, but this example seems illustrative.

Answer (score 7):

I believe so, as I migrated it over.

The key indicators are in the line that [random points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115750/should-this-question-have-been-migrated#comment-302108) (emphasis mine):

> The following **solution** looks like it needs **refactoring**

So the poster has a *working solution* and is looking to *refactor* it.

In my mind, that makes it a *much* better fit for Code Review.